# How to wrap quotes in a div in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the below string, what is the best way to wrap the quotes in a div?

```
let someString = 'This is some string. \" Wow what a cool string.\" It would be cool if I could wrap the quotes in a div. \" Yeah that would be cool. \" Wish I knew how'
```

So the outputed string would look like:

```
'This is some string. <div> \" Wow what a cool string.\" </div> It would be cool if I could wrap the quotes in a div. <div> \" Yeah that would be cool. \" </div> Wish I knew how'
```

I'm attempting to style these quotes differently on my html page from the rest of the string.

Comment: Find `("[^"]*")` replace with `<div>$1</div>`

Comment: Btw, JS treats single quotes the same as double quotes, so it parses _someString_ into `This is some string. " Wow what a cool string." It would be cool if I could wrap the quotes in a div. " Yeah that would be cool. " Wish I knew how`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply replace instances of the quotes with whatever tag you want to wrap them with.
An example:

```
const someString = 'This is some string. " Wow what a cool string." It would be cool if I could wrap the quotes in a div. " Yeah that would be cool. " Wish I knew how'

someString.replace(/(".*?")/gm, "<div>$1</div>")
> '"This is some string. <div>" Wow what a cool string."</div> It would be cool if I could wrap the quotes in a div. <div>" Yeah that would be cool. "</div> Wish I knew how"'
```

This will find all strings that start and end with quotes and replace them with the same string but with added HTML tags.